# Android app - free to paid strategy

Tags: android, google-play

I have an Android app which is free but contains ads.

I'm thinking of making a paid version by publishing an unlocker which will remove ads and will enable more functionalities (functionalities which are all included already in the free version).

The problem is that to do so, I will have to "limit" the functionalities in the free version to be able to enable them with the unlocker.

But doing so those users who have the free version today (i.e. with full functionalities) will get angry when they get an update which will limit the functioanalities and thus I will get bad reviews on Google Play.

Is there a way to keep full functionalities for those who have the app from before, while limiting the functioanlites for those who download the app for the first time?

Comment: Why not making the paid version add-free...?

Comment: It will be ad-free, but I also want the paid version to have more functioanlities. The free version, as it is per today, has full functionalities. That means I will have to "limit" the functionalities of the free version and then those who have the free version with full functionalities today will receive an update which will give them limited functionalities...not the best user experience...

Comment: Make an intermediate version of the app that stores a boolean indicating that the newer version should have full functionality, or possibly have a look at Google Tag Manager.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there a way to keep full functionalities for those who have the app
>   from before, while limiting the functioanlites for those who download
>   the app for the first time?

No you cannot do that with the same app, since you have already rolled out a full featured app as free.
What you can do now is you can take down your existing app from store(unpublish) and upload a new one with In app purchase capability. Hence existing users will not get affected and you will have a Free app which new users can download and upgrade to get more features. But by doing so you will loose reviews on your existing app.

Comment: I thought so, but then I will loose all my reviews and the name/popularity my app had achieved so far...

Comment: @user3514699 Yes you will loose them all. Otherwise try to add more features and roll out an In app purchase app :)